# How to display the material tab?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I don't have a material tab in blender, like this one (the globe):

https://youtu.be/ITfkvQdWaRA?t=489

This is what I have:

[image]

How do I make it appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you probably don't have selected your object. Select your object by right-clicking it and then it should appear the awaited tab.

In your case right-click the ground.